# Installing lessc with NPM - UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

Tags: node.js, less, npm

I want to install the **lessc** provided from [NPM](https://npmjs.org). (on OSX)

Firstly, I installed the current version of NodeJs: 0.10.15.
It includes NPM.

Now I launch the famous command:

`npm install -g lessc`

and I obtain this error:

```
npm install -g lessc
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lessc
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lessc
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lessc
npm ERR! Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1350:32)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:963:10)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:463:15)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:573:24)
```

On the net, I found a [workaround](http://thomashunter.name/blog/npm-ssl-errors/):

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

But when I relaunch the command, I get now:

```
npm install -g lessc
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lessc
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/lessc
npm ERR! 404 'lessc' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "lessc"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/me
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR! code E404
```

I'm very new to NodeJs world and its packager.

Is there something I can do to manage to install `lessc`?

Maybe I forgot some env variables.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, the issue was trivial:

Actually I was inspired by this [Play plugin](https://github.com/jmparsons/play-lessc).

And the shown command is:

```
npm install -g lessc  // lessc nonexisting
```

instead of

```
npm install -g less
```

Now, with the workaround specified above, that works.